# Invalid `prisma.job.findMany()` invocation: Database Path error while using SQL Lite connecting to my database on Vercel

Tags: sqlite, next.js, prisma, vercel

I am getting a 504 internal server error while trying to access a page which loads data on my next.js application. The error states:

```
Error retrieving users: PrismaClientInitializationError: 
Invalid `prisma.job.findMany()` invocation:

Error querying the database: unable to open database file:
```

From what I understand it's no opening the database and I'm not sure if it's the path. locally the path is working and running fine. I am using prisma to connect to the database.

How can I fix this?

This is the full error on vercel log:

```
Error retrieving users: PrismaClientInitializationError: 
Invalid `prisma.job.findMany()` invocation:


Error querying the database: unable to open database file: /var/task/node_modules/.prisma/client/../database/invensisdb.db
    at An.handleRequestError (/var/task/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:174:7205)
    at An.handleAndLogRequestError (/var/task/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:174:6358)
    at /var/task/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:177:2908
    at async /var/task/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:177:3123
    at async t._executeRequest (/var/task/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:177:10621)
    at async Careers (/var/task/.next/server/pages/api/careers/post_get.js:64:25) {
  clientVersion: '4.15.0',
  errorCode: undefined
}
```

My Schema Locally

```
// This is your Prisma schema file,
// learn more about it in the docs: https://pris.ly/d/prisma-schema

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "sqlite"
  url      = "file:../database/invensisdb.db"
}


model User {
  id        Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  username     String  @unique
  password     String 
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
}

model Job {
  id        Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  location  String
  title     String
  description   String
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
}

model JobApplication {
  id        Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  email      String
  location   String
  startDate  String
  primarySkills  String
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
}

model Projects {
  id        Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  name     String
  location      String
  description     String
  duration     String
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
}
```

[image: my folder structure]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this Link: [SQLite support for Vercel](https://vercel.com/storage/postgres)

It looks like SQLite isn't supported by Vercel, and they recommend using [Vercel Postgres](https://vercel.com/storage/postgres) as an alternative.